# Allwinner tablets factory resetting for no reason

Tags: tablet, factory-reset

I'm selling a lot of low cost A10 Allwinner tablets (Android 4.0.4). Some of my customers say that their tablet has been factory resetting (like anyone can do using the volume up/power buttons trick).

When a factory reset is automatically applied? Can a high battery drain cause the reset?

Comment: Battery drain *shouldn't* cause a factory reset, but it's hard to say what the tablet might be doing under those conditions.  A factory reset ough to never happen without being manually triggered except perhaps in the case of some security feature (e.g., after failed attempts to password unlock it).

Comment: Thanks for editing my question. Yes I expect that no factory reset is applied without the user's confirm. So you're saying that Android will never do it in any case. I found someone else have the same problem: http://androidforums.com/sprint-hero-all-things-root/373144-automatic-factory-reset-when-battery-drains-completely.html Thanks for your comment.

Comment: A factory reset can be applied to Android phones using the USSD attack. It's not my case, just for your knowledge.

Comment: Another case. Someone claims the problems is in the Android build installed in the tablet: http://androidqueries.com/unexpected-factory-reset-now-i-cant-change-my-sound-settings-605.html

Comment: @Seraphim'shost Possible to let us know what tablets you are selling?

Comment: Very hard to say... No brand. I know there's Allwinner a10 inside.